Summability of integrand and continuity of integral function
Problem
Let $f:[0,\infty) \to (0,+\infty)$ a continuous function such that
$$\sup_{t>0}\{t^n f(t)\}<+\infty, \quad \forall n\in \mathbb{N}.$$
$(a)$ Prove that the map $$t\mapsto t^{x-1}f(t)$$ is $\mathcal{L}^1\left((0,+\infty)\right)$ for every $x\in (0,+\infty)$.
$(b)$ For $x\in (0,+\infty)$ define the integral function:
$$F(x)=\int_{(0,+\infty)} t^{x-1}f(t)\ dt$$
and show that it's continuous.
$(c)$ Compute, if they exists, the following limits
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} F(x), \quad\quad\quad \lim_{x\to +\infty} F(x).$$
My solution
$(a)$ Define $\varphi(t)=t^{x-1}f(t)$ for every $x\in (0,+\infty)$.
Then, $\varphi\in \mathcal{L}^1\left((0,+\infty)\right) \iff \int_{(0,+\infty)}|\varphi(t)|\ dt<+\infty$.
By def, $\varphi$ is a positive function, therefore the absolute value is superfluous.
Then, I have that:
$$\int_{(0,+\infty)} \varphi(t)\ dt =\int_{(0,+\infty)} t^{x-1}f(t)\ dt$$
The function $g(t,x)=t^{x-1}f(t)$ is continuous and so I have to check the convegence of the improper integral in the extremes of integration.
First, it's comfortable to write the following
$$\int_{(0,+\infty)} \varphi(t)\ dt=\int_0^1 \varphi(t)\ dt + \int_1^{+\infty}\varphi(t) \ dt$$
Then, I observe that the hypothesis $\sup_{t>0}\{t^n f(t)\}<+\infty,\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ give me that $\sup_{t>0}\{f(t)\}<+\infty$ for $n=0$ and so $\exists M\in \mathbb{R_{>0}}$ such that $f(t)\leq M$. So, I have that:
$$\int_0^1 t^{x-1}f(t)\ dt \leq M\int_0^1 t^{x-1}\ dt=M\int_0^1 \frac{1}{t^{1-x}}\ dt$$ that is a convergent integral for every $x\in (0,+\infty)$.
Furthermore, the hypothesis $\sup_{t>0}\{t^n f(t)\}<+\infty,\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ give me also that $\exists k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $t^{x-1}f(t)\leq t^kf(t)$ because $f(t)$ need to converge with order $k$ at least. So, I have that:
$$\int_1^{+\infty}t^{x-1}f(t)\ dt \leq \int_1^{+\infty} t^k f(t)\ dt <+\infty, \quad\forall x>0$$
So, I have that
$$\int_{(0,+\infty)} \varphi(t)\ dt <+\infty \Longrightarrow \varphi\in \mathcal{L}^1\left((0,+\infty)\right)$$
$(b)$ I think that $\varphi\in \mathcal{L}^1((0,+\infty))$ for every $x>0$ allows me to conclude that $F$ is continuous in its domain.
$(c)$ I have that:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}F(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\int_0^{+\infty}t^{x-1}f(t)\ dt=$$ $$=\lim_n\int_0^{+\infty} t^{\frac{1}{n}-1}f(t)\ dt=\int_0^{+\infty}\lim_n t^{\frac{1}{n}-1}f(t)\ dt=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{t}f(t)\ dt$$
and the second limit:
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}F(x)=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\int_0^{+\infty}t^{x-1}f(t)\ dt=\lim_n\int_0^{+\infty} t^{n-1}f(t)\ dt=$$ $$=\int_0^{+\infty}\lim_n t^{n-1}f(t)\ dt=+\infty$$
Are my answers correct? I'm not really sure about $(b)$ and the second limit in $(c)$ doesn't look much correct to me, any help?

Your answer to b) is wrong. For c) you have to justify interchange of limit and integral.

Ok, on $(c)$ my problem is whether it is correct to move from the limit in $x$ to the one by sequences. If this is ok, I would justify the passage with the limit and integral exchange theorem since the sequence I obtain is of continuous (and therefore integrable) functions.

For $(b)$ I tried to increase the magnitude of the integrand (which should be possible since the integrand is $\mathcal{L}^1$) but I can't justify it well...

Or otherwise I could prove that there exists a neighborhood in which the integrand is increased by a summable function with respect to the variable $x$...
